# Intent.EXTRA_STREAM in Android

Tags: java, android

Why does it say **String** in Android documentation website, when EXTRA_STREAM is a URI. I'm trying to understand how to read android documentation.

[EXTRA_STREAM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM)

**String** EXTRA_STREAM

A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String is the type of the Constant Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, any extra name must be a String.

Answer (score 0):

In information technology, a Uniform Resource Identifier is a **string** of characters used to identify a resource.